# Arrange several lists of plots using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some lists of plots named p1,p2,p3, each one contains c plots (c is a constant number).
I would like to use grid.arrange as follow:

```
  grid.arrange(p1[1],...,p1[c],p2[1],...,p2[c],p3[1],...,p3[c],ncol=2)
```

I tried to the following commands but they do not work:

```
  do.call("grid.arrange",c(p1,p2,p3,ncol=2))
```

or

```
  do.call("grid.arrange",c(list(unlist(p1),unlist(p2),unlist(p3)),ncol=2))
```

But the interesting thing is the following command works (but not really what I want)

```
  do.call("grid.arrange",c(p1,ncol=2))
```

So how can I arrange some lists of plots?

Comment: have you tried `do.call(grid.arrange, list(p1, p2))`?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried the command that you suggested. It returns the same errors as the commands I did above: only 'grobs' allow in "gList".

Comment: Odd, it works for me. How about: `do.call(grid.arrange, lapply(list(p1, p2), ggplotGrob))`?

Comment: I tried to implement your command and it returns Error in UseMethod("ggplot_build") : 
  no applicable method for 'ggplot_build' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest :)) I really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for do.call,

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 = replicate(3, ggplot(), F)
p2 = replicate(5, ggplot(), F)

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = c(p1, p2), ncol=2)
```